# UIScrollView stops scrolling when another view loads and dismisses

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` and another `UIView` (`view2`) inside it.  '`view2`' scrolls fine when app launches. But, whenever I show and dismisses another VC (a `UIImagePickerControler` in this case) `scrollView` becomes non scrollable.

I have set the content size at `viewDidAppear` , so this must be something related to AutoLayout constraints. I've tested with all the constraints removed but still getting the same result.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but make sure your viewDidAppear: method doesn't assume it's only called once.  It will be called again when the second view controller is dismissed.